# Sharepoint Dev in VS2010 without SP2010 Server - will this work and how do I get the 14 hive files from SP2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have heard that if you import the 14 hive files from a SP2010 server machine, you can develop for sharepoint in VS2010 without actually having SP2010 server on your machine.

Where would I get my hands on these 14 hive directory files?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wasted effort. First, you would have to dig all dependencies from the GAC as well. Second, you won't be able to debug and single line of code without an actual SharePoint installation.

The best practise is to have a standalone installation on a VM win Windows Server 2008 R2. Working in a dedicated virtual machine provides the best developer experience.

Comment: I'll Second the above answer! Just install a SharePoint instance, use the easy set up scripts if you're looking to get started easily: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2010/10/28/announcing-sharepoint-easy-setup-for-developers.aspx